# What is the real meaning of Planck's constant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-constants

My teacher told that [Planck's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) is $h$ and nothing more. So please explain what actually plancks constant is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the real interpretation of Planck's constant and what are its origins?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44965/)

Comment: Also see: [Physical Interpretation of Planck's Constant](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287514/)

Answer (score -4):

Simply put, electrons orbit a nucleus at fixed distances. Let's call those distances a, 2a, 3a, etc. Planks constant is the amount of energy needed for the electron to move from a to 2a or from 2a to 3a. As you can probably tell by the name, this amount of energy is a constant.

Comment: But according to bhor quantumn theory as number of orbitals increases the difference in enegy between the orbital decreases negatively.so ,how could you say that h is difference in energy between two orbitals ? How could you say that is a constant?