# Why Lagrangian is negative number for a relativistic massive point particle?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, normalization

In the special relativistic action for a massive point particle,

$$S=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathcal {L}dt,$$

why is the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal {L}=-E_o\gamma^{-1}$$

a negative number?

Comment: I'm just guessing this is the relativistic action for a free point particle, but some clarification of your question would help...

Comment: Because by convention, we want the action to be minimized in normal cases, not maximized. It's a convention: we could redefine $S\to -S$ which would then be maximized. For a massive pointlike particle, the proper time along the straight path is actually *maximized*, recall the twin paradox (the traveling twin ages less than the stationary one because of time dilation!), so one has to take $S$ to be a negative multiple of the proper time for the action to be *minimized* along the classical path.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451

Answer (score 7):

At the classical level (meaning $\hbar=0$), to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations (i.e. the special relativistic version of Newton's 2nd law) from the action $S$, an overall non-zero (possibly negative) multiplicative factor is irrelevant. In this case, the normalization is chosen so that the Lagrangian

$$\begin{align} L~=~&-\frac{E_0}{\gamma}~=~-E_0\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}\cr 
~\approx~& \frac{1}{2}m_0 v^2 -E_0 \qquad\text{for}\qquad v\ll c\end{align}$$

recovers the well-known expression for the kinetic energy (up to an additive constant) in the non-relativistic limit $v\ll c$. So a bit oversimplified, the negative sign is caused by the huge rest energy $E_0=m_0c^2$. Note that an additive constant in the Lagrangian does not affect the equations of motion.

Answer (score 6):

The argument I have seen is that the action is the length of the geodesic i.e.

$$ \text{path length} = \int ds $$

but we know that the trajectory of a free relativistic particle is the one that maximises the path length. So by writing:

$$ S = -m\int ds $$

we get an action that is **minimised** for the correct path (the $m$ is there to make the dimensions correct).

Comment: And how about non relativistic $L=mv^2/2$?

Comment: Generally what matters is that the action is stationary $\delta S=0$, as is most easily seen from the path integral. Whether the classical path corresponds to a maximum, minimum or saddle point of the action is practically immaterial.

Answer (score 2):

All these notes have important and interesting physical content; however I prefer the solid ground of the proof given in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics. For the hamiltonian to represent the total relativistic energy, the Lagrangian must have a minus sign before the rest energy and in an inhomogeneous way

$L=-\frac{m_0c^2}{\gamma}-V \Longleftrightarrow h=\gamma m_0c^2+V$

Note that this way, both the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian are unique.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian $L = T-V$ describes the energy of motion minus the energy of position. Hence the negative sign of that Lagrangian for a relativistic action for massive point particle describes the deceleration of that massive particle because of the huge potential energy, which will be always greater than its energy of motion.