# Relativistic action is negative or positive number?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, point-particles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why lagrangian is negative number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52155/why-lagrangian-is-negative-number)

In the special relativistic action for a massive point particle, 
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathcal {L}dt,$$
where the Lagrangian 
$$\mathcal {L}=-E_o\gamma^{-1}$$ is
a negative number then the action is a negative or positive number?

(*in my research it was negative, the result was correct but minus sign make me to ask this question*)

Comment: As was explained at least twice in the comments of [your last question on this topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52155/520) and it's associated answer the correct answer is *"Yes, the action can be either negative or positive."* Stop worrying about this and pay attention to the way you *use* the thing: you don't care about the value, you care about paths for which the integral is stationary.

Answer (score 0):

The value of action itself is of no meaning, you can always add something to it, if you do not like its sign.