# Interchanging of variation and integration operator for holonomic systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

Meirovitch says in his "Principles and Techniques of Vibrations" (1997) on p.85:

> In the case of holonomic systems, the variation and integration processes are interchangeable (...)

which means that

$\delta \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot{q}) dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta L(q,\dot{q}) dt$

subject to

$f(r_1(q), r_2(q),...,r_N(q),t) = 0.$

where $L$ is the Lagrangian, $q$ are generalized coordinates, $r_i$ are the coordinates of points of mass in the configuration space and $f$ is the constraint.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: If you like this question, you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93176/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the discussion about commutativity of the $d/dt$ and $\delta$ operator! It does not (seem to) answer my question, though. How come that $\delta \int L dt = \int \delta L dt$ holds and what has holonomy got to do with it?

Comment: interchange has to do with [uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#Proof_of_Theorem) (having to do with path-independence, thus holonomic vs non-holonomic systems which are path-dependent)

Comment: @NikosM.: Thanks a lot for the hint! I'll investigate into that..