# Why $\delta (\partial_{\mu} \phi_{i}) = \partial_{\mu} (\delta \phi_{i})$ on field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

While one are using Hamilton Principle on density Lagrangian, he may find this

$$\delta (\partial_{\mu} \phi_{i}) = \partial_{\mu} (\delta \phi_{i})$$

Why this statement are true?

Comment: Related: [Lagrangian Mechanics - Commutativity Rule $\frac{d}{dt}\delta q=\delta \frac{dq}{dt} $](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93176/2451).The argument is essentially the same in field theory.