Deriving Klein-Gordon equation from Euler-Lagrangian equation: Taking partial derivative inside
Lagrangian for Klein-Gordon equation is given by
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi - m^2\phi^2/2.$$
To derive Klein-Gordon Equation I have to Compute derivative in Euler-Lagrange equation.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-\partial_\mu \left(\frac{\partial L }{ \partial \partial_\mu  \phi}\right)=0\tag{2.3}
\end{equation}
see Peskin equation 2.3.
or
$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \partial_\mu\phi} (\partial_\nu \phi\partial^\nu\phi)$$
= $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \partial_\nu \phi}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi}\partial^\nu\phi+\frac{\partial \partial^\nu\phi}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi}\partial_\nu\phi\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial \partial_\nu \phi}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi} \partial^\nu \phi +\frac{\partial \partial^\nu\phi}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi}\partial^\lambda\phi\eta_{\lambda\nu}\right).$$
now I am taking the
$$\frac{\partial \partial_\nu \phi}{\partial \partial_\mu \phi} = \frac{\partial_\nu \partial \phi}{\partial_\mu \partial \phi} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} =\delta^\mu_\nu.$$
similarly second term becomes
similarly second term becomes
$$\eta^{\nu \mu} \eta_{\lambda\nu} = \delta^\mu_\lambda$$
and final derivative becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}(\delta^\mu_\nu \partial^\mu\phi + \delta^\mu_\lambda \partial^\lambda\phi)=\partial^\mu\phi.$$
I have following doubt can I take
$$\partial (\partial_\nu\phi) = \partial_\nu (\partial \phi)?$$
many books gives
$$\delta(\partial_\nu \phi) = \partial_\nu (\delta\phi).$$
is it true for $\partial$ also? is $\partial$ and variation $\delta$ are same?
Is it correct to take $\partial$ (the derivative which appears in Euler Lagrange equation) inside?
or in other way can i assume that
$\partial_\mu \phi$ and $\partial_\nu \phi$ is independent if $\mu \ne \nu$?
Here derivation of Euler Lagrange equation is given with $\delta$ variation notation, which seems to be correct as we vary the action.
enter link description here
Since Lagrangian density L is $L(\phi, \partial_\mu\phi)$ in phase space $\phi$, $\partial_\mu \phi$ are field variable and derivative and can be treated independently in phase space, or $\partial_\mu \phi$ and $\partial_\nu\phi$ are two independent variable if $\mu \ne \nu$.
Hence partial derivative of $\partial_\mu\phi$ with respect to $\partial_\nu\phi$ will give a $\delta^\nu_\mu$. This explains the derivation without exchanging the $\delta$ or $\partial$.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557328/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93176/2451 and links therein.

can i assume that partial derivatives of phi with respect to x1 and x2 are independent where x1 not equal to x2

Comment to the post (v13): The notation is not clear. What does a lone $\partial$ mean? To reopen this post consider to give a definition of $\partial$ or avoid the notation entirely.

I think that $\partial$ means the derivative that appears in Euler-Lagrange equation instead of variation $\delta$

see Peskin equation 2.3 for Euler Lagrange equation

is $\partial$ that appears in Euler Lagrange equation (see Peskin 2.3) and variation $\delta$ are same

There are no isolated $\partial$ in P&S eq. (2.3); only partial derivatives wrt. fields and their derivatives.

I understood. Euler Lagrangian equation involves  partial derivative with respect to independent field and their derivatives. But I want to know my calculation to arrive $\partial_\mu \phi$ by taking its derivative of Lagrangian with respect to field derivative is correct or not? Kindly verify

Since Lagrangian density L is $L(\phi, \partial_\mu\phi)$ in phase space $\phi$, $\partial_\mu \phi$ are field variable and derivative and can be treated independently in phase space, or $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial_\nu$ are two independent variable if $\mu \ne \nu$.
Hence partial derivative of $\partial_\mu \phi$ with respect to $\partial_\nu \phi$ will give a $\delta^\nu_\mu$. This explains the derivation without exchanging the $\delta$ or $\partial$, this is the same case in classiclal mechanics $L(q,\dot{q})$, where $q$ and $\dot{q}$ are treated independent
