# Origin of Hamilton's variational principle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

My question is what is the theoretical origin of [Hamilton's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton's_principle). I mean is there any rigorous mathematical proof of this principle from some more basic principles?

Comment: yes, you derive the Lagrangian and apply Legendre transforms.

Comment: In what way does [How Hamilton's Principle was found?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98332/) fail to answer your question? Or [Why the Principle of Least Action?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899)

Comment: More possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9/2451 and links therein. Specifically, the derivation of Hamilton's principle from Newton's laws is discussed in http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451