# Why the action of a relativistic point particle is considered to be negative?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, point-particles

The action of a relativistic point particle is its negative rest energy along its worldline, the parameter being its own proper time.
$$ S = - mc^2 \int d\tau $$
[(see Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Single_relativistic_particle)

Is there a particular reason why the action is considered to be negative?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52155/2451 and links therein.