# What is the intuitive concept of the action of a relativistic point particle?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, point-particles

The action of a relativistic point particle is its negative rest energy along its worldline, the parameter being its own proper time.
$$ S = - mc^2 \int d\tau $$
[(see Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Single_relativistic_particle)

Action is energy multiplied with time. How can I imagine the "action" of an unaccelerated point particle which does not seem to deploy any kind of energy?

Further explanation: An oven may emit a certain number of Jsec in a given time, but not an unaccelerated point particle.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to understand relativistic action of a massive point particle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163525/)

Comment: Why would you want to "imagine" the action? The action is a thing such that you can derive the equation of motion taking derivatives, no more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant interval is the object to be extremized. The infinitesimal interval $$
ds^2~=~c^2dt^2~-~dx^2~-~dy^2~-~dz^2 
$$
is also
$$
ds^2~=~\left[c^2~-~\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2~-~\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2~-~\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2\right]dt^2~=~(c^2~-~v^2)dt^2
$$
We may then take the square root of this and multiply by the invariant mass
$$
mc^2ds~=~mc^2\sqrt{1~-~v^2/c^2}dt
$$
Now assume that the velocity is small, and use binomaial theorem
$$
mc^2ds~\simeq~mc^2\left(1~-~\frac{v^2}{2c^2}\right)dt~=~mc^2dt~-~\frac{1}{2}mv^2dt.
$$
We can see that the last term is the kinetic energy with the wrong sign. To correct for this we must then define the action with the negative sign.

Comment: This is not my question, I know that. I am referring to the units of action (energy multiplied with time)

Comment: @Moonraker Those units are the same as in nonrelativistic mechanics. First understand these concepts there before moving to relativistic mechanics.