# Euler-Lagrange equations in relativity (Goldstein)

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

In order to have a  covariant formulation of special relativity, we stop using the time $t$ as a parameter and we choose some invariant parameter.
In Goldstein (third edition), chapter $7.10$, it goes through this derivation making an argument about why proper time $\tau$ can't be the parameter we are looking for because of the constraint on 4-velocities.
\begin{equation}
u_\nu u^\nu=c^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
It then chooses another parameter $\theta$ and derives Euler Lagrange equations using this new parameter $\theta$. At the end he chooses
\begin{equation}\theta=\tau\tag{*}\end{equation}
Why does this allow us to ignore the constraint $(1)$?

We're basically using proper time the whole time but ignoring the constraint and using at the end.

I've read something similar on another book (which used $s=\int ds$ where $ds^2=dx^\nu dx_\nu$, thought) which said that to find the variation of action:

\begin{equation}
S=\int Lds
\end{equation}

We should also consider the variation of $ds$ with coordinates. Then it introduces a new parameter that is eventually replaced by $s$. How do you account for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since the [4-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) $$u^{\mu}~:=~\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau} \tag{U}$$ by definition is the 4-position differentiated wrt. [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) $\tau$, the condition
   $$\begin{align}
   c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2
   ~=~&\pm \eta_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu} \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}
   \cr~\Updownarrow~&\cr
    u^{\mu}  u_{\mu}~=~&\pm c^2 \end{align}\tag{C}$$
   holds independently of any worldline (WL) parametrization $\theta$ [in Minkowski signature $(\pm,\mp,\mp,\mp)$, respectively].
2. Goldstein considers the action for a massive relativistic point particle
   $$\begin{align} I ~=~&\int_{\theta_i}^{\theta_f} \! d\theta ~\Lambda, \cr  
   \Lambda~=~&-mc\sqrt{\pm x^{\prime}_{\mu}x^{\prime \mu}}, \cr 
   x^{\prime \mu}~:=~\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\theta},\end{align}\tag{I}$$
   which is WL reparametrization invariant $\theta\to\tilde{\theta}=f(\theta)$.
3. It is important to realize that the 4 quantities $x^{\prime \mu}$ are not constrained by eq. (C). ($\leftarrow$ This is OP's main question.)
4. The corresponding [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)$^1$
   $$ \frac{d}{d\theta}  \left( \frac{mc x^{\prime}_{\mu}}{\sqrt{\pm x^{\prime}_{\mu}x^{\prime \mu}}}\right)~\approx~0\tag{EL} $$
   is WL reparametrization covariant.
5. After the variation, it is legitimate to choose the parametrization $\theta=\tau$. The EL equation then simplifies [with the help of eq. (C)] to
   $$ \frac{d(m u_{\mu})}{d\tau} ~\approx~0,\tag{EL'}$$
   i.e. the [4-acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration) is zero on-shell.
6. Goldstein makes the pragmatic observation that if we a priori choose $\theta=\tau$ in the Lagrangian $\Lambda$ [and somehow ignore the constraint (C)], then we can formally write down the correct EL-equation [with $\theta=\tau$].
7. Although Goldstein obtains the correct EL-equation by this dirty trick, it is conceptionally very misleading. In fact, if we literally choose the parametrization $\theta=\tau$ in the action prior to the variation then the action would become a constant off-shell:
   $$ \begin{align} I ~=~&\int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f} \! d\tau~(-mc)\sqrt{\pm u_{\mu}u^{\mu}}\cr
   ~=~&-mc^2(\tau_f-\tau_i).\end{align}\tag{I'}$$
   Phrased differently: all virtual paths would have the same value, i.e. the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_Action_Principle) becomes ill-defined.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* 2nd edition; Section 7.9.
2. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* 3rd edition; Section 7.10.

--

$^1$ The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo EOM.

Comment: With the last update $(C)$ is always valid (since it is a consequence of the chosen metric) and we can use it in point 7 with no problem, is that right?

Comment: Yes (depending on what you mean by no problem).

Comment: I mean that with $(C)$ not being only a property of the solutions of the $EOM$ we can use it in the off-shell action.

Comment: @Qmechanic Those are some very good points.  I'm not too sure about the statement "and somehow ignore the constraint (C)". It seems vague. I don't have a copy of Goldstein, but what is the justification? It's easy for me to have missed something obvious, due to my nearly 20 year hiatus from advanced physics.

Comment: Hi @joseph h. Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I suspect the topic of this post may be too esoteric if one doesn't have access to Goldstein. The underlying theme is similar to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701748/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic Okay thanks. I’ve just ordered a copy of Goldstein. We actually used Goldstein from Year 2 onwards to pgrad. I had a copy but recall giving it to one of my students who wanted to pursue a physics degree (he was initially interested in engineering). I will have a read of the link you provided soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Proper time $\tau$ can be defined as the parametrization of $x^\mu(\tau)$ such that :
$$u_\mu u^\mu = \frac{\text d x_\mu}{\text d\tau}\frac{\text d x^\mu}{\text d\tau} = c^2$$

If you choose an arbitrary parametrization $x^\mu(\theta)$, then you have :
$$\frac{\text d x_\mu}{\text d\theta}\frac{\text d x^\mu}{\text d\theta} = \left(\frac{\text d\tau}{\text d\theta}\right)^2 \frac{\text d x_\mu}{\text d\tau}\frac{\text d x^\mu}{\text d\tau} = \left(\frac{\text d\tau}{\text d\theta}\right)^2  c^2$$

so contraint $(1)$ is indeed lifted.

Since the observables are $x^i$ in terms of $x^0$, the parametrization of the trajectory is irrelevant. The action and the equations of motion should be invariant under reparametrization. It is easier to work out the Euler-Lagrange equation with an arbitrary parametrization, and choose a sensible one (proper time) at the end.

Comment: "Since the observables are xi in terms of x0, the parametrization of the trajectory is irrelevant."

So using $\tau$ from the beginning and applying the constrainst when you finish is fine. Why does he even bring up this matter?

Comment: Using $\tau$ *is* applying the constraint $u_\mu u^\mu = c^2$. If you do this first, when deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations, the trajectory $x^\mu + \delta x^\mu$ must be parametrized wr proper time as well, which brings complications. If you start by letting the parametrization be any $\theta$, then the variation $\delta x^\mu$ has no constraints and the Euler-Lagrange are easy to derive