# Confused about relativistic point particle action in MTW

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, point-particles

In [MTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_(book)) page 179 exercise 7.2 they give the following action for an particle in an electromagnetic potential.

$$I = -\frac{1}{16 \pi} \int F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} d^4x + \frac{1}{2}m \int \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dz_{\mu}}{d\tau}\,d\tau + e \int \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau} A_{\mu}(z)\,d\tau. \tag{7.5}$$

However, I am puzzled by the middle term.
$$\frac{1}{2}m \int \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dz_{\mu}}{d\tau}\,d\tau.$$

Wouldn't the relativistic term here would be roughly,
$$mc^2 \int d\tau~?$$

This looks like a non-relativistic term, which seems strange given the use of four-vectors here.

Can someone clear up this confusion for me?

Comment: Why? $\frac{1}{2}m \int \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dz_{\mu}}{d\tau}d\tau$ is the kinetic energy term of the action and the inner terms are 4-velocities. Why do you think it should be $m \int d\tau$ ?

Comment: Because the Relativistic Lagrangian for a free particle is $m\int d\tau$.

Comment: It looks like $\frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dz_{\mu}}{d\tau} = c^2$, so I guess it is the same thing... Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: OP's has a point. It is inconsistent to use proper time $\tau$ as a world-line parameter *before* performing the variation in the stationary action because not all virtual paths are parametrized by their proper time. Only *after* the variation has been performed, and the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) obtained, it is consistent to use proper time $\tau$ (of the solution curve) as a world-line parameter, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149204/2451).

More details: In this answer we focus on the middle term in eq. (7.5) since the first & last terms are only spectators to OP's question. MTW explains on the previous page 178 that $\lambda$ denotes an arbitrary world-line (WL) parameter, while $\tau$ denotes [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time).
More generally, the "master" action for a relativistic point particle is

$$\begin{align}I[z,e]~=~&\int_{\lambda_i}^{\lambda_f} \! d\lambda~L,\cr
L~=~&\frac{\dot{z}^2}{2e}-\frac{e(mc)^2}{2}, \cr 
\dot{z}^2~:=~&g_{\mu\nu}(z)~ \dot{z}^{\mu}\dot{z}^{\nu}~<~0,  \cr 
\dot{z}^{\mu}~:=~& \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\lambda},\end{align}\tag{A} $$

where $e(\lambda)>0$ is an einbein field, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362807/2451) related Phys.SE post. This action (A) has WL parametrization invariance.

The usual [square-root action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451) [that OP implicitly mentions in their last expression] can be recovered by integrating out the einbein field $e$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137857/2451) Phys.SE post.

If we instead fix a gauge
$$e(\lambda)~=~e_0~:=~\text{some constant},\tag{B}$$
then the action (A) becomes proportional to MTW's middle term (7.5) [up to an irrelevant constant term $-\frac{e_0(mc)^2}{2}$ in the Lagrangian]. *After* the variation, one may relate the WL parameter
$$\lambda~=~\frac{\tau}{me_0} + \text{constant}\tag{C}$$
to proper time.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: ...Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The action you have in your question is for a relativistic massive charged particle in an EM field, and the term $$\frac{1}{2}m \int \frac{dz^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dz_{\mu}}{d\tau}d\tau$$ is the kinetic energy of the action. But in your last comment above, you state that the particle is *free*. The action you also refer to $m\int d \tau$ is that for a free relativistic particle in a curved spacetime.

How you get that term is by noting that the standard Lagrangian for  such (an on-shell) particle is $$\mathcal{L}(\dot{z}) = -mc\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{z}^\mu \dot{z}^\nu}$$ for a particle that has a worldline described by $z(λ)$, parametrized by an affine parameter $\lambda$ with a spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

If $\lambda=\tau$  (the proper time), then $\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{z}^\mu \dot{z}^\nu} = \sqrt{c^2}=c$ which means the Lagrangian reduces to $$\mathcal{L}(\dot{z}) = -mc^2$$ which is a constant. As you seem to be working in units where $c=1$ this implies the action is given by $$I=\int\mathcal{L}(\dot{z})\ d\tau=-m\int d\tau$$

Comment: I am asking about a particle in an EM field. I expect it to have field terms and an additional term which is the only term present for a free particle.

Comment: Then why did you ask about a free particle in your comment? You've confused the issue. Can you edit your question with your last comment above? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think it's clear as it stands. I am referencing an equation in MTW, and I was just asking about the kinetic energy term, as you described it, in that Lagrangian. Anyways, I think the matter is resolved by noting the equivalence between the two as I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Ok then. Good luck with your studies. Cheers.

Comment: Note that $g_{\mu\nu} \dot z^\mu \dot z^\nu= c^2$ is true only on-shell, and is not true for generic trajectories which are explored during the minimization of the action.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer by Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/638083/156895) for details about the subtleties in choosing the proper time as the curve parameter.