# Lagrangian non-relativistic limit to the non-relativistic action: lagrangian of a free particle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, relativity, variational-principle, variational-calculus, point-particles

Let be $u=|\bar{u}|$ the speed of a free particle (at constant speed) of mass $m$ that is moving in relation to an inertial frame. Why we initially introduce the term $\epsilon$ to the free lagrangian

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
L_\mathbf{free}=\epsilon\sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}=\epsilon \sqrt{1-\frac{\{[x'(t)]^{2}+[y'(t)]^{2}+[z'(t)]^{2}\}}{c^{2}}}
\end{equation}

and then to prove that $\epsilon$ it is really $-mc^2$?

Probable references:

1. Classical electromagnetic radiation 3rd, Marion (*english version*), pag. 516$\to$ 522.
2. The classical theory of fields - 4th revised, English Edition, Landau-Lifshitz - Chapter 2 pag. 26 § 8 **(*)**.
3. Classical electrodynamics, Jackson, 3rd edition, pagg. 579-580-581-582 (*english version*), chapter 12, (**formula (12.7)** for the formula $(2)$).

---

4. Classical electrodynamics, Jackson, pagg. 567-568 (italian version).
5. Goldstein pag. 300 (italian version) chapter 7, eq.: 7.141.

Comment: Can you please include a reference for all your equations? Presumably, they explain what $\epsilon$ is, and why you should put it there. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37996/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259688/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461559/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic 12, covariant trattation at sight of the relativistic Lagrangian...Dynamic  of the relativistic particles. I have not inserted images this time :-)

Comment: Jackson uses $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Qmechanic No, absolutely. I believe that this concept is linked to those pages that I do not understand. Too difficult for me.

Comment: What does Jackson use instead?

Comment: @Qmechanic In chat I have finded the $\epsilon$: eq. [12.11]: $L_{\text{int}}=-\epsilon\Phi+\frac ec\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{A}$.

Comment: @Sebastiano 1) any reference in English? Most of us don't understand Italian. 2) What does eq. [12.11] have to do with the Lagrangian in the OP? There are no EM fields in your Lagrangian...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You have 100% all the reasons. I have given to the moderator where I have finded the $\epsilon$. At this moment I'm searching into Marion book: classical electomagnetic radiation 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly a repetition of the argument presented in an earlier question of yours and in the chat therein.

Lagrangians are an exercise in repetition. You cannot *derive* a Lagrangian per se. You already have to know the answer.

- step 1: 
  You start with the equations of motion of a system (be electrodynamics, classical mechanics, QED etc.) that you *know* from other methods.
- step 2:
   You know the Euler-Lagrange equation, that needs a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ as input and that gives the equation of motion as output: $$ \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left (\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right ) = 0, $$where $q$ is your variable of choice (e.g. position $x$), and $p = \partial \mathcal{L}/\partial \dot{q}$ is the *conjugate momentum*.
- step 3: 
   You **invent** a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ that, when put into E-L, gives you back your equation of motion.
- step 4: So what's the point of re-writing known equations of motion in Lagrangian formalism? It's more compact, it's a scalar (does not require immediate choice of basis), it's more elegant, manifestly symmetric, easier to implement constraints.

In your specific case at hand, relativistic mechanics.

You **already know** that the momentum $\mathbf{p}$ is given by:
$$ \mathbf{p} = \gamma_{\mathbf{u}} m_0 \mathbf{u}, $$ where $m_0$ is the *rest* mass and $\gamma_{\mathbf{u}} = 1/\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$, and the energy $E$ (or the Hamiltonian $H$, same thing) is given by:
$$ E = H = \gamma_{\mathbf{u}}m_0 c^2. $$

Then you make stuff up until you notice that this specific choice:
$$ \mathcal{L}  =  -\frac{m_0 c^2}{\gamma_{\mathbf{u}}}$$ gives you the correct answers.

Specifically:

- momentum: $$ \mathbf{p} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}}} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{u}} = \gamma_{\mathbf{u}}m_0 \mathbf{u},$$

and

- energy: $$ H = \mathbf{p}\cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}} - \mathcal{L} = \gamma_{\mathbf{u}}m_0 c^2.$$

In all of the above I assumed zero external potential(s) $V(\mathbf{r}, \dot{\mathbf{r}})$.

**EDIT**

The OP seems to be wanting a "proof" for his factor of $\epsilon$.

So let's do that.

Let's "guess" a lagrangian of the form: $\mathcal{L} = \epsilon / \gamma_{\mathbf{u}} = \epsilon \sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}$ like in your question.

Let's calculate $\left (\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}\right ) = \left (\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}\right ) = -\epsilon\frac{u_x/c^2}{\sqrt{1-u_x^2/c^2}} = -\epsilon \gamma u_x/c^2$. Where I'm doing it in 1D for clarity.

This has to be equal to the momentum $p_x = \gamma m_0 u_x$, because we know it from relativistic mechanics.

Equate the two: $$-\epsilon \gamma u_x/c^2 = \gamma m_0 u_x \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \epsilon = -m_0 c^2 !$$

Comment: Kindest then my question not is very clear. :-( My question is: why do I have to introduce the term $\epsilon$ for the free lagrangian and then prove that $\epsilon=-mc^2$?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. You're just trying to guess what specific Lagrangian gives you the right answer. The way presented in your book is just another way of doing it, which happens to work (even though it is not guaranteed to). They're guessing it depends on the gamma factor $\gamma$ and on some proportionality constant $\epsilon$. You then have to figure out what $\epsilon$ is in order to give you the correct answers (like at the end of my answer). I'll edit the answer to try and address your concern now.

Comment: Now it is ok :-) is perfect! :-) My sincere grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the reason behind the "-1" that someone gave this answer?

Comment: “Private” as in a chat room? Which is still public.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98675/discussion-between-superciocia-and-sebastiano).