# Relativistic mechanics: Does the action rely on a particular choice of the inertial frame?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, inertial-frames, action

We know that the Lagrangian of a relativistic particle is as follows: $$L = -mc^2\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2},$$ with the action being the integral of this Lagrangian with respect to time in the reference frame of the particle. My question is, does the action rely on a particular choice of the inertial frame?

Answer (score 1):

No, the action $S=-E_0\tau$ is minus the rest energy $E_0=m_0c^2$ times the lapse $\tau$ of [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) of the massive particle. Both factors $E_0$ and $\tau$ are invariants, so the action $S$ is independent of the choice of coordinate system. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: I do not understand how τ is invariant. Surely the lorentz transforms state otherwise?

Comment: $\tau$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations. Can you see why?