# Why Lagrangian has this form in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

One can derive the geodesic equation by Euler-Lagrangian equation,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x^\gamma} - \dfrac{d}{ds}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (dx^\gamma/ds)}\bigg) =0
\end{equation}
where $$\mathcal{L}= \bigg[  -g_{\mu \nu}\dfrac{dx^\mu}{ds}\dfrac{dx^\nu}{ds}\bigg]^{1/2}.$$
And by searching in some references, i didn't find any clear reason for this form of Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$.
Can you give me the reason for this form of Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Worldline action of point particle in gravitational field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/618080/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The integral of the Lagrangian is the proper time elapsed along the particle's worldline $\gamma$:
$$
\tau = \int_\gamma d \tau = \int_\gamma \sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu} = \int_\gamma \sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{ds} \frac{dx^\nu}{ds}}ds = \int_\gamma \mathcal{L} \, ds.
$$
So any solution to the Euler-Lagrange equations for this "Lagrangian" will extremize the proper time elapsed between the endpoints of $\gamma$.  But geodesics extremize the proper time between their endpoints, and so a solution to the Euler-Lagrange equations will be a geodesic.